# Is it correct to say "he led me through a path"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Is it correct to say: "he led me through a path in the forest"?

Here, path has been used as a synonym of 'road' or 'street' and is trying to convey the idea that you are traversing a path in the middle of a forest, hence walking 'through'.

Is it correct?

Comment: It's not incorrect.  "He lead me along a path ..." might work better.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. Try: *He led me through the forest on a path.* Neither would you say *He led me through a road in the city.* Try: *He led me through the city on a road.*

Comment: One goes _on, along, down_ (or _up_) a _path_. Not _through_, which requires 3 dimensions: _through the gardens,_  or _the yard_, but not _the path_, or _the lawn_, which are at most two-dimensional.

Comment: @JohnLawler What about "he went through the intersection," which is (I believe) two-dimensional but valid?

Comment: You need a car or some 3-D vehicle to go through an intersection. You can't walk through an intersection; you walk _across_ it.

Comment: @JohnLawler [Ngram Viewer disagrees.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=walked+through+the+intersection%2Cwalked+across+the+intersection&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) For once, it appears to be right on this point; [Google Books shows lots of examples of "walked through the intersection."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22walked%20through%20the%20intersection%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: Maybe in Scotland. I know that “to go through” can mean to go from Edinburgh to Glasgow or vice versa, so maybe the usage of “through” is different to other places more generally.

Comment: You can go through a forest, so why not a path in the forest? Not a path over the moors though. You can also go through a maze or a network of streets.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+a+path%2Calong+a+path%2Cthrough+a+path%2Cvia+a+path&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for 'along/by/through/via a path'.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google‘s English Dictionary (provided by [OxfordLanguages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/)) we have the following definition:

> **Through:** moving in one side and out of the other side of (an opening, channel, or location).

With this definition in mind, it should be clear that we cannot walk through a path as need there to be a clear entrance and exit in order for this to make sense in line with the above definition.

Instead, your sentence could be corrected  (as mentioned in the comments) one of the following:

- "he led me along a path in the forest"
- "he led me through the forest along a path"

In the second sentence, we keep the word "through" but this time we use it to describe your movement in and out of the forest. If you refer back to the definition, you will see that this now makes sense.

Comment: A small number of paths have no start or finish but most do.

Comment: Google is a Company and a search engine. It does not author content retrieved by a search, nor has it any responsibility for it. Please identify the real source of this definition (if you really believe a single dictionary definition provides evidence for usage).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to say, "he led me through a path in the forest"?

This is perfectly normal and a good use of English:

To the fluent reader, this suggests that the path is narrow (probably because of tall undergrowth on either side).

It also has the nuance of the narrator entering the path and emerging from it at the other end.

If the writer had used "along", the "flow" of the writing would have been lost when the writer had to explain that the path ended.

We have no difficulty at all with such a sentence as

*"He led me through the trench to an area of open ground."*